# Adsense banner drown page content

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, adsense

I have tried everything, searched the net for two hours or even more and I still did find nothing.

The problem:
adsense banner just drowns my page content. it looks like the javascript is about 400-500px height, when it have to be 90px. `Banner looks good, but the content below the banner is unclickable`. `If you still don't get it`.

you can see it on `www.statyba24.lt` `The theme` I have used is `Esplanade by OneDesigns.`

Thanks for help.

Comment: The page has a banner in the middle that is 90px high and 728 px wide - this is what is asked for in the script variables google_ad_width and google_ad_height.  What part is actually wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good with google chrome. Try put height:90px and overflow:hidden in the wrapping div.

Comment: yes, the banner looks good, but try to click on content below the banner and you will see the problem...

Comment: oh, I see. But then I think you should try overflow:hidden; change <div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 5px;"> to <div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 5px; overflow:hidden;">